# Flex List Item's Accessory View

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I am new to this Technology.
I want to display Accessory View(Right Side Arrow Button) in Flex List View.
How can I do this.?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by accessory view you mean something like [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html); where you are displaying details on the selected item in the list.

First create a [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) with a custom [itemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html).  The itemRenderer should display the item's label and the arrow.

Second, create a component to display the detail from the selected item in the list.  The implementation of this component will depend greatly on the data you want to display.

Third, listen to the [change](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#event%3achange) event of the List, and when the item changes, update the values being displayed in your "accessory" component.

Comment: @user810199 Did it help?  Did it answer your question?  If so, you should consider marking it as such.  If not, you may consider elaborating on the issues you are having.